# Getting endless loop in trying to fetch all records of a mysql column

Tags: php, mysqli

Inside my database I have a table **service** I want to display all the entries of a column **step** for the selected ids. Here is my code.

```
<div class="panel panel-body">
<?php
$sql="SELECT step FROM `service` WHERE id=$someid";
$result=mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$resultcheack= mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($resultcheack>0) {
    //$steps=array();
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    while (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
        echo "<li>".$row['service_step']."</li>";
    }
}

?>      
</div>
```

when I run this code in xampp it gives me the first entry of the column **step** infinite times. I must be doing something very silly in my code. Will someone help me in displaying all the entries of that column. 
I am quite new to php. Thanks.

Comment: `while (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)` that's where the trouble starts. You're looping with the wrong logic/method here.

Comment: Stop mixing html + php + mysql together

Comment: Thanks Fred, for your help. What should I keep there?

Comment: logic: if row count is true, loop over rows, not over row count. You can call this an educational answer ;-) I'm the type who likes to teach someone "how" to fish ;-)

Comment: [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) returns the number of rows returned by the query. It doesn't change inside the loop, that's why the loop never ends.

Comment: You're also missing the `<ul></ul>` tags btw. If those are elsewhere, then it's already wrong. Least from what you posted.

Comment: thanks you all. It is really bless to have such good people around to guide new learns like me. Thanks one again for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: I'm curious; how did you assign the `$someid`? Seems to me that you stand at being open to a serious SQL injection. You don't want your db to get compromised/deleted, do you?

Comment: No Fred-ii, I don't want to compromised my db security. I have another page which takes user email as input (I have used prepared statement there) and after comparing user email with another table of my db I gets $someid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)` will always return true, use **while** like this

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<li>".$row['service_step']."</li>";
}
```